# how to webservicetarget url dynamically in nlog for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nlog

how to web service target URL dynamically in NLog for Xamarin.Forms in NLog.Config file. need to get a to a variable instead of hardcoding.

```
<target name="webservice" 
        xsi:type="WebService"
        url="{var:url}"
        protocol="JsonPost"
        proxyType="NoProxy" 
        namespace="{var:namespace}"
        methodName ="InsertLogs"
        encoding="utf-8">
        <parameter name="Datetime" type="System.String" layout="${time}"/>
        <parameter name="level" layout="${level}" />
</target>
```

Comment: Unfortunately,it is not recommended that change the target URL dynamically in NLog.Config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load and modify your target at runtime and set the URL:

```cs
var target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("webservice") as WebServiceTarget;
target.Url = new Uri("https://my.url/logs");
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that NLog v5.0 adds Layout-support for `Url`-option.

There are NLog v5.0 pre-release available for try out.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target

Comment: Any idea how to use the layout with the URL attribute?? I see where they added support but cannot figure out how to actually do it since I don't see any examples anywhere..

Comment: @lucky.expert Sounds like a new stackoverflow-question about now NLog Layouts can be used: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layouts#target-configuration-with-layout